# Is there any way to add a round cap on a pattern brush stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, patterns

I'm trying to create laces with rounded ends, so I created my pattern then turned it into a pattern brush with Auto-Between cornering.

No matter what I do, the "Round Cap" setting under Stroke settings has no effect. If I use a pattern fill I get the round cap but then I don't benefit from the pattern snaking its way along the line like a real shoe lace.

Is there any way to get this to work or a work around? I'm using the latest version of Illustrator CC 2015.

[image: Round cap doesn't work on a pattern brush]

Comment: I submitted a feature request which is probably all I can do I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a circle of the same diameter and slice it in half, align it to the end of the line and merge the shape.
Another way is to make the line a shape in the object drop-down (outline stroke) and then do the same, with creating a cirlce... but then it converts your shape to a line graphic.
If you change any line to a brush, the line properties are not the same, because they are not working with solid lines, but curves and the ends of the brush reflect this.

Comment: I know how to "hack" some circles onto those line ends, but it's a pity that there is simply no option to have a pattern brush with a round cap. Has no one ever needed this feature? I remember bumping into this limitation a while ago.

Comment: Don't think this has been changed in any of the Illustrator versions since its inception. If you want, you can always do the line and then change the line width itself at different points and then also warp the line to give that curve...